# How to wrap image tag with anchor tag to make it clickable?

Tags: css, image, element, clickable

Hy, I have the following situation:
I am trying to change the design of my feedly-index page. (I can not change the HTML)
And I am facing a problem I coulnd't solve the past two hours.

In the HTML there are some div elements with random IDs and '_content' at the end.
Within these div's there is an img tag - what I want to do is to wrap this img-tag with an anchor-tag to make it clickable.

```
      Situation:
      <div id='{SOME_RANDOM_ID}_content'>
          // a bit of text, a few <br> and some other tags here
          <img src='LINK_TO_AN_IMAGE'>
      </div>


      What I want as outcome:
      <div id='{SOME_RANDOM_ID}_content'>
         // a bit of text, a few <br> and some other tags here
         <a href='LINK_TO_AN_IMAGE'> 
                <img src='LINK_TO_AN_IMAGE'> 
         </a>
      </div>
```

Is this even possible with CSS?

I could make it work with JavaScript, but the div's are loaded dynamically via AJAX:/
So the JavaScript Script would just run for the current div's but not the one which are loaded dynamically.

Comment: You have just wrapped the image with a tag. Why does CSS comes here?

Comment: Whether your css got changed after you did that?

Comment: You are not able to edit the html?

Comment: No, CSS is not able to add link-like functionality.

Comment: I've edited my concern =) check again

Comment: No thats not possible via CSS. But you can do it using Javascript

Comment: @user3649090 you can check my answer for the approach to do it in js :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with just CSS because CSS is meant or styling the page and not or adding dynamic elements to the page.

But we can do it using JS.

As you are creating those elements using ajax call. On the success callback of the ajax call, you can wrap the image with `a` tags.

for example:

```
$.ajax({
   url : "/make.php"
}).done(function() {
   var images = $("div img");
   $.each(images, function() {
     $(this).replaceWith($("<a href=''>"+this.outerHTML+"</a>")); //construct url dynamically via some variable
   });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/xupuc/1/edit)**

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to edit the html this could be tricky.

It can't be done with pure css... css can't create links.. I mean it could be possible with js i suppose, besides that if the ids are random it makes it even more difficult. 
--edit additional--

If you could wrap the whole area that holds the divs inside a div then you might have a chance with jquery...

e.g:

```
<div id="holderdiv">

<div id='{SOME_RANDOM_ID}_content'>
          // a bit of text, a few <br> and some other tags here
          <img src='LINK_TO_AN_IMAGE'>
      </div>

</div>
```

You can then use jquery to make all instances of ***#holderdiv > div > img*** a link to the image path?

Comment: I could make it work with JS, but the div's are loaded dynamically via ajax :/
So the JS Script would just run for the current div's but not the one which are loaded dynamically.

Comment: yes it a tricky one. If you could wrap the whole area that holds the divs inside a div then you might have a chance with jquery. e.g:
I will update my answer above.

Comment: If you add the js in the success callback of the ajax method, then you can wrap the images with anchor links.